# Meta Marketing API: Instagram Profile URL in WEBSITE_CLICKS Objective

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-marketing-api

Reading through Meta's documentation they specify: "You should not create WEBSITE_CLICKS ads that link to your Facebook Page or Instagram profile. This can result in API error and it also creates a poor advertising experience."

We are looking to use Meta's API to create ads that run to an IG profile to mimic the "visit instagram profile" boosted post experience. Anyone have experience trying this and does it really throw an API error if we only selected Instagram explore, story and feed placements?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/ads-api/guides/call-to-action/

Comment: have you found the answer for this yet! Need this for a feature. Thanks in advance!